# ncftp connection time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Is there a way to make ncftp hold the connection open longer than the default? a ping every 10 sec or something? I feel like after I push a change up to the server before I can verify everything is working as expected and get back into ncftp the connection is closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use ncftp?

If you can change application to `curl` or `wget`, those should be able to send some `NOOP` as keepalive